# Complex txt Reading

Tags: java, list, networking

**First of all, I am using Java.**

So, I am creating a random obscure word generator for some reason and honestly, it would be ridiculous using multiple if statements or a switch for something of this scale. I want my program to choose a random word, and it's definition from a list of **thousands** of words.

***Here is one of the words in the list:***

```
 wyrd   the personification of fate or destiny
```

For some reason my source has occasionally used *tabs* and occasionally used *spaces*, then the line changes.

***In a simpler explanation:***

```
 wyrd   the personification of fate or destiny
 wynd   narrow street or lane
```

I need to choose a random word, either **wyrd** or **wynd** and put it into a variable, I then need to put the relative definition into another variable but on a much larger scale but with much more words.

What I'm asking is, should I use a text document with a large amount of words, or get the list off the internet?

**Please comment questions... on my question...**

Comment: How about putting all the words and definitions in a database?  Depending on the db, you could select a random row (using, e.g., SQLite's "ORDER BY RANDOM()"), or you could give each row an incrementing ID and select a random ID from within that range.

Comment: My reactionary opinion is that someone somewhere will be providing a service that can help you.  `Wordnik`, for example is described here http://www.programmableweb.com/news/words-youll-love-these-2-apis/2009/11/10